# On-the-fly reprojection to a "world" projection causes lat/lon raster to become invisible

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I have a global elevation raster in latitude and longitude. I want to use it as the basemap in a world projection system (e.g., Mollweide, Robinson).

When I set the coordinate system to Mollweide (or Robinson) and enable on-the-fly projection, the global topography raster map disappears until I zoom in far enough that there is no "no data" area left in the display. In other words, I need to make sure that the display doesn't include any of the curved map projection edges.

I have tried using gdalwarp outside of QGIS as well, and then importing the already-projected raster, using gdalwarp:

```
gdalwarp -s_SRS 'EPSG:4326' -t_srs '+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' coarse_6am_topo_021000.tif out.tif
```

However, this projected map cuts off the north polar region (not sure why this is happening either), so I am not sure what to do -- it would be nice if the on-the-fly reprojection worked!

Answer (score 4):

According to https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-August/033674.html, gdalwarp (and OTF as well) fails on your use case.

The best workaround is to clip the raster to the real world, as described in [Valid values of mollweide projection in QGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95305/valid-values-of-mollweide-projection-in-qgis)

Comment: Thank you for the help! To clarify for others wondering: the first link answers the GDAL question, while the second seems to be to help with the on-the-fly reprojection.

Comment: Unfortunately, clipping the raster as suggested here has not worked for me. I have also simply reduced the bounds of the raster, even in a quite extreme way (removing 10 degrees off each edge), with no success.

Comment: OTF does **NOT** work, you must reproject. Furthermore, try an ellipsoid instead of a sphere.